# CSS image grid spacing issue

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to add a image grid to a section in my page. I've used this code:

```css
#champ-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
}

#champ-container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="champ-container">
  <img src="image" />
  <img src="image" />
  <img src="image" />
  <img src="image" />
  <img src="image" />
</div>
```

aHere is what it currently doing:

[image: gallery current display]

There is a large space between each image, and I can't figure out why. I want maybe a 10px gap between the images. For this grid, I'm looking for three across and the rest wrapping to the next row. I don't understand how the third image ended up as its own row. All images are the same size: 288x164.

Comment: You use `champ-container` as a class in your `html`, but as an id in your `css`.

Comment: I created a snippet of your code, perhaps make that reproduce your issue here as the code presented does NOT do that

Answer (score 0):

You have used `champ-container` class in html but you have used it as an id. Change your **css** to this

**Correct CSS:**

```
.champ-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;   
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content); 
}

.champ-container img {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#champ-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;   
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, max-content);
}

#champ-container img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="champ-container">
<img src="image" />
<img src="image" />
<img src="image" />
<img src="image" />
<img src="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely useful. Please add some explanation as to why/how your code solves OP's problem.